# iOS - Pop-up custom subview after click

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Maybe this is a simple problem, but I spend some time try to solve it and so far I failed.

I want to show custom view with a few of button after I clicked a block of text. I try to add and remove this view form subview but it's doesn't work.

Can you give me some tips about my problem?

Thank you for your help.

my code
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var simpleView: SimpleView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myTextField.delegate = self
    self.simpleView.removeFromSuperview()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
    println("works")
    self.view.addSubview(simpleView)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
    println("works2")
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide us the source code!!

Comment: Are you trying to show a popover view ?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better set the hidden property of simpleView instead of removing and adding the view.

Answer (score 0):

put a container view in your main view and set the visibility hidden. when you want to show the popup, set the visibility to visible and load the view inside the container. To get the popup 
look and feel ,you can use a transformation to animate.